# Why does my ComputeAsync take more time than my ComputeNonAsync?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I'm building a Monte Carlo simulation for bond pricing. I do this by:

1. I have a functor (InterestRatePathCreator) that, when called with a seed, will generate and return a vector (vector A) of interest rates. The idea is that I need to run this 10,000 times, and since each calculation is independent from the next, I figured async would work well here.
2. I return this vector (vector A) to my BondPricer which does some additional calculations, such as discounting the cash flows I'd receive from a bond with specifications I provide. This yields a single number (the bond's price during that iteration) which I store in a vector (vector B).
3. I then average the items in that vector (vector B) and that is my bond's price.

For some reason, as these operations are performed, my Async computation is slower than my non-Async computation, leading me to believe I'm doing something wrong.

The only difference between the two computations is that one uses Async while the other doesn't (see below).

**Functor Object** (Generate Random Interest Rates)

```
vector<double> InterestRatePathCreator::operator()(int seed) const {

    vector<double> yieldCurve;
    vector<double> discountRates;

    mt19937 randEng(seed);
    normal_distribution<> normDist;

    auto newInterestRate = [this](double previousRate, double norm) {

        double currentRate = previousRate;
        double expArg1 = (riskFreeRate_ - 
                         ((volatility_ * volatility_) / 2));
        double expArg2 = volatility_ * norm * sqrt(timeSteps_);
        currentRate *= exp(expArg1 + expArg2);

        return currentRate; 

    };

    yieldCurve.push_back(discountFactor_);
    double interestRate = discountFactor_;

    for (int k{1}; k <= timeSteps_; k++) {
        interestRate = newInterestRate(interestRate, normDist(randEng));       
        yieldCurve.push_back(interestRate);
    }

    for (int j{}; j < timeSteps_; j++) {
        discountRates.push_back(1.00 / pow(1 + yieldCurve[j], j));
    }

    return discountRates;
}
```

**Async Price Computation**

```
void MCBondPricer::computePriceAsync() {

    InterestRatePathCreator irp(paymentFrequency_, 
    discountFactor_, riskFreeRate_, yearsRemaining_, volatility_); 

    vector<std::future<vector<double>>> bondData; // FUTURE
    vector<double> discountedCashFlows;
    vector<double> cashFlows;

    bondData.reserve(trials_);
    discountedCashFlows.reserve(trials_);
    cashFlows.reserve(timeSteps_);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Several bond-related calculations removed.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    generateSeeds();

    for (auto& seed : seedStorage_) {
        bondData.push_back(std::async(irp, seed)); // ASYNC
    }

    for (int i{}; i < trials_; i++) {

        vector<double> discountRates = bondData[i].get(); // GET
        int bondPrice{};

        for (int j{}; j < cashFlows.size(); j++) {

            bondPrice += discountRates[j] * cashFlows[j];

            if (j == cashFlows.size() - 1) {
                discountedCashFlows.push_back(bondPrice);
            }
        }
    }

    price_ = quantity_ * (1.0 / trials_) * 
    std::accumulate(discountedCashFlows.begin(),
                    discountedCashFlows.end(), 0.0);
}
```

When I do 10,000 trials on Async I get 2.5 seconds, when I do non-Async I get 1.5 seconds. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Are you running an optimized build?  Please post your compilation settings.

Comment: You don't specify launch policy. That could be an issue. You presumably want std::launch::async and DO NOT want std::launch::deferred.

Comment: Try async-running 10 batches of 1000, as opposed to 10000 batches of 1. With your setup any gain will be outweight by initial setup cost.

Comment: @WilliamClements If I specify one with a launch::async and a large number of trials, it crashes. I guess my laptop can't handle it and my program is opening too many threads?

Comment: @Jeffrey How do I do that? How do I specify how I'd like async to handle it?

Comment: You'd need a class with operator() that loops over some amount (say 1000) of iterations. Yours currently only process one